# Xamarin/Visual Studio 2017: which .net version to pick for mobile development?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I just started to develop with Visual Studio 2017 / Xamarin, Target platforms are Android and iOS.

I found no reference about whether there is any dependency between the target .net version and the Android/iOS version. Are they completely unrelated, or is there such a table?

More details:

When I initiate a project, I need to specify a .net framework version, choices range from 2.0 to 4.6.1. Before I can build it, and to let me specify a correct target for simulation, I need to specify a target Android Version (choices range from 2.1 (API 7) to 8.0 (API 27), there is a similar choice for iOS.

Theoretically, since AFAIK Xamarin automatically bundles the compiled app with the .net code (contrary to what happens under Windows, where the .net framework must be installed as a separate system component) any combination ahould work with any target OS, but is this really the case?

Thanx, Armin.

Comment: Which "2.0"  are you referring to - .net framework 2.0 or .net standard 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technical details behind would give you a long answer, but it might not be 100% correct.

**Mono supports multiple .NET profiles, but not the latest**

If you use Visual Studio for Mac to create a Mono project (console app for example) today (Feb 6, 2018), you should be able to see the newest .NET profile it supports is 4.7 (should be 4.7.0 to match .NET Framework), and C# language is 7.1.

> Note on Windows, .NET Framework 4.7.1 is out, and C# 7.2 is supported.

**Xamarin uses latest Mono**

The final build of your mobile apps (iOS or Android) would bundle the latest Mono runtime. Thus, the .NET profile and C# compiler you can use would be determined by that Mono version.

So in your case today, you should be able to target .NET profile 4.7.0 and C# 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

The framework version of the shared library doesn't in any way affect the target framework for each device, it only affects which platform you could target and what .NET classes and methods are actually available in this library.

Comment: To check, I choose .net 2.0 and compared the choice of platforms with when set to 4.6.1, and both have the same choice of platforms (Android, iOS, and WIndows (UWP)). Looking deeper into which project types I can choose for each platform, I found no difference between .net 2.0 and 4.6.1. So it seems, that all available .net framework implementations are completely platform independent ... almost too nice to be true :-) aybe I need to install more exotic platforms in addition to the big three to see a difference?